# Exception while IsOneWay is True

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF. I have a small question to ask.

Let's assume `IsOneWay=true` is set in for one of the OperationContracts in my service contract. Let's say when client calls this method and some exception occurs in the method what happens.

Besically I want to know when this property is set to true how the exception behaves.

Please reply.
Thanks in Advance
Sudhanshu

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the type of error:

- if it's an error in your actual service code, then nothing will happen, since the server cannot communicate back anything - the service operation just won't happen. The client channel will be in a faulted state for any future non-one-way call, i.e. unusable for future operations, so you'll have to recreate it to use it again
- if it's a security or timeout error, the exception on the client will still happen - those aren't affected by the `IsOneWay=true` setting

Does that answer your question? If not: what do you need to know?

Comment: It answered my doubts, I was wondering whether I should put a `try catch` block in my one-way method (which is non-critical, so it's ok to fail), even though I decided to log it.